# Basic c++ program, what have i done wrong?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and found this exercise on a website. I tried completing it and this is how far i have got.

can someone please tell me if i am on the right direction, if not, what is wrong?
Also please explain any code you write. 
"Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz".

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++ ){
        while (i * 3 ){
            cout << "Fizz"<<endl;
            while (i * 5){
                cout <<"Buzz"<<endl;
                while ( 1 * 3 && 1*5){
                   cout <<"FizzBuzz"<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `if`, and not `while`...

Answer (score 5):

You're approaching things wrong. Why do you need the `while (i*3)`? Do you know what a `while` does? Is that supposed to check the remainder?

Hint - use conditionals (`if`) and the `%` operator to check the remainder.

No full code for you! Learn to debug! (this is the best thing you can do at this stage)

Comment: i dont want the full code, what is the point i wont learn. Thanks for your hint by the way.

Comment: i tried this 
          for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++ ){
          if (i % 3 == 0) {

          cout << "Fizz"<<endl;
          }
          if (i % 5 == 0) {

           cout <<"Buzz"<<endl;
           }

           if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5) {
           cout <<"FizzBuzz"<<endl;

Comment: @VbFg did you debug? Do you print anything when the number is not divisible by 3 or 5? You should check for both 3&5 division before the rest, otherwise it'll print everything.

Comment: can i ask you an unrelated question please. I really have an interest in programming, I have only started recently and my only option is online videos, books and sites like this. You cant get far on your own or i can't, i was thinking of going to another country to learn programming just programming and then come back to the UK and go to university to study software engineering. I know if i go to university now i wont be able to code well, they just teach you lots of theory. Do you think this is a good idea or what should i do? Thanks

Comment: @VbFg read books on programming. Universities teach you how to think, which has its own value. You won't directly apply much of what you learn in a university unless you work in academia afterwards, but it has its value nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
while (i * 3 ) {
```

with

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, an answer below says the only error is the brackets ( i forgot them) but is that true?

Answer (score 0):

1. To test for divisibility test for remainder of 0 with %
2. whiles should be ifs
3. For loop will print 0 to 99

Try something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i <= 100; i++) {       
    if ((i%3 != 0) && (i%5 != 0)) {
        cout << i;
    }
    else
    {    
        if (i%3 == 0) {
            cout << "Fizz";
        }

        if (i%5 == 0) {
            cout << "Buzz";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```